# How to have the frontend show the appropriate image size?

Tags: images

When I include an image, that is 1600 pixels wide, in an image block and set it to be 'Full width', it shows properly in the backend. But in the frontend, where it is to fill the entire width of the screen, it is downsized to 640 pixels wide, also when there is more, or much more, vertical space available.

So, even with a window that's, say, 1500 pixels wide, the image that is included is like so:

```
<img decoding="async" width="1426" height="713" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ep1.1.jpg?resize=640%2C320&amp;ssl=1" alt="" class="wp-image-124343">
```

Notice the width property, and the resize querystring variable.

What is downscaling this image automatically? How do I avoid this when the vertical space exists to show a larger version of the image?

I can see that the images in question do not have a srcset attribute, but I thought this was default Wordpress practice?

Answer (score 0):

It might be your theme applying some CSS style via the `styles.css` file, or an inline CSS style.

Use the Developer Tools in your browser to inspect that graphic element to see if it has some inline CSS, or has a class for that image (or even an `img` rule). The inspector can tell you where that class is coming from.

Lots of online help on how to use your browser's developer tools. A very worthwhile thing to know about and use.

Comment: Thanks. perhaps I wasn't clear enough. The image isn't shown at 640 pixels wide, it's shown at full width, the width of the window. But the image that is showing is 640 pixels wide. I'll update the question to make this clearer.